# Populate a TableView with ObservableMap that has ObservableList as a value

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I'm trying to create an ObservableMap that has ObservableList of custom objects as a value like this

```
Map<String, ObservableList<MyClass>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
ObservableMap<String, ObservableList<MyClass>> myObservableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(myMap);
```

After searching about binding of ObservableMap to tableview, I haven't found how it would be if the value is a collection. All that I've seen is binding of observable map that has a value of a custom class. I'm thinking that it should not be so different as I would only want the values of the keys to be binded to the tableview and keep track of the changes that would happen to the key and the values inside it.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
Map<String, ObservableList<DMSchedule>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
ObservableMap<String, ObservableList<DMSchedule>> myObservableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(myMap);

TableColumn<DMSchedule, String> dayColumn;
TableColumn<DMSchedule, String> subjectNameColumn;
TableColumn<DMSchedule, String> startTimeColumn;
TableColumn<DMSchedule, String> endTimeColumn;
@FXML
private TableView<DMSchedule> myTable;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    final ListChangeListener<DMSchedule> listListener = new ListChangeListener<DMSchedule>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends DMSchedule> change) {
            System.out.println("Detected a change!");
            while (change.next()) {
                System.out.println(change.getFrom());
                System.out.println("Added on list? " + change.wasAdded());
                System.out.println("Removed on list? " + change.wasRemoved());
            }
        }
    };

    dayColumn = new TableColumn<DMSchedule, String>("Day");
    subjectNameColumn = new TableColumn<DMSchedule, String>("Subject");
    startTimeColumn = new TableColumn<DMSchedule, String>("Start Time");
    endTimeColumn = new TableColumn<DMSchedule, String>("End Time");

    myObservableMap.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, ObservableList<DMSchedule>>) mapChange -> {
        if (mapChange.wasAdded()) {
            mapChange.getValueAdded().addListener(listListener);
        }
        if (mapChange.wasRemoved()) {
            mapChange.getValueRemoved().addListener(listListener);
        }
    });

    myObservableMap.put("M", FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    myObservableMap.get("M").add(new DMSchedule("M", "07:00", "08:30", "testSubj", "testSection"));
    myListOfMap.addAll(myObservableMap);

    myTable.getColumns().addAll(dayColumn, subjectNameColumn, startTimeColumn, endTimeColumn);

    myTable.setItems(myObservableMap);
```

And I'm kind of lost how will I set my ObservableList values to the table and columns.

I would want to interact with the table the same way as if I'm binding an ObservableList to the tableview. Like selecting tablerow would return `MyClass` objects(assuming that a row factory has been made). I have already figured out how to add listeners for the change in value of keys and values inside a map. The only problem that I have left is to bind the `ObservableList<MyClass>` of each keys inside `myObservableMap`. How could I possibly do it? I hope that you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?